# Graph API Explorer token retrieves more information than OAuth token with same scope

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am having trouble with my own access token, for some of my friends I can only retrieve public data. I generated two access tokens:

1. Generated from Graph API Explorer page
2. Generated from my web app using OAuth

Both access tokens have the same (extensive) scope.

However, queries using the tokens behave differently - but only for some of my friends. The token from the API explorer behaves as expected: it yields a broad results with private information. The OAuth token seems to retrieve public information only, but only for some of my friends. For most of my friends, both tokens retrieve the same information.

I put an an image with a couple of screen shots to https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfjyM.png -- The results from the access token debugger are shown in the red inset. The results of the graph query are shown in the back, accessed with https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

[1]:

Comment: Any chance those friends also use the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Igy provided the pointer that helped, thanks! - some of my friends seemed to have disabled a lot of information under "Settings -> Apps -> Apps other use". Therefore, my token couldn't retrieve that information. And some of those friends also used Graph API Explorer, and the Explorer token correctly gave more results.

Comment: Yep, if the person whose data you're trying to retrieve is also a user of the app, the app can retrieve their data more freely than if they weren't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igy provided the pointer that helped me, thanks a lot.

Here is a recap:

- It seems like some of my friends disabled a lot of infos using "Settings -> Apps -> Apps other use". My token couldn't retrieve that information, correctly. Of course, you as Friend can see that information but it won't be passed onto an app.
- Also, the same friends used the Graph API Explorer in the past. Therefore, the Graph API Explorer had access to that information.